# $x^Ty\leq 1, \forall\text{ y with }||y||_2 = 1 \iff ||x||_2\leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

I came across this:

> This follows from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
>   $x^Ty\leq 1, \forall\text{ y with }||y||_2 = 1 \iff ||x||_2\leq 1$

where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$

When I try to do it myself, this is what I get:

$|x^Ty|\leq ||x||_2||y||_2 \leq ||x||_2$.

Is it because $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and can take different values, then  $||x||_2\leq 1$

Comment: Try $y = \frac{x}{\|x\|_2}$.

Comment: So we would have $|x^Ty| \leq |x^T \dfrac{x}{||x||_2}| = 1$?

Comment: What is $x^Tx$?

Comment: Its $x^Tx=||x||^2_2$. got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of Cauchy-Schwarz to get the first inequality is fine, it shows that $|x^Ty| \leq 1$ if $||x||_2 \leq 1$ and $||y||_2 = 1$. For the other direction, go with what a comment suggested and use $y = x / ||x||_2$.